# Laptop backlight problem?

Tags: laptop, display, backlight

I have this laptop with a weird problem. The screen suddenly turned off while I was working,it didn't fix the problem by restarting it. I could still see a picture on the screen when the sun is shining on it.

When i press the Fn+F6  combination to turn on my backlight, it just flashes for half a second and turns off. I replaced the faulty inverter a week ago so i doubt that it's the inverters problem because the screen wouldn't get any kind of light from the bulb before.

Another thing i noticed that the picture was red after turning the laptop on(the colours got normal after a minute ) , and the lower two corners of the screen weren't lit as good as the entire screen.

Could it be the backlight bulb?

Answer (score 3):

It could be the bulb or, you won't like it - it could be the inverter again.

Without seeing it, there is simply no way to help you out for certain.

It is just impossible to know. The inverter could be the wrong part or just faulty - it "fires" up and the bulb flashes but the charge was incorrect and it overloads/turns off, or it could simply be the bulb is broken and it can't stay on for more than a few seconds.

If someone was to bring a laptop to me and I was to see the exact thing you are saying, I would personally think it was the inverter, but I would test both - When it is open, I would quickly plug it in to another screen as I always have a spare panel* laying around, and if it doesn't fire up, I would order a new inverter.

(*As long as the connector is correct, you can test - it just won't be correct resolution/size)

I just can't even guess for you as I have seen the same symptoms from both parts failing :(

Comment: +1 Wil: Screens starting up with a red tint that slowly corrects itself has often been down to bad capacitors on the display main power feed. This does sound like power feed/inverter problem - especially if the DC power feed to the inverter is the bit at fault.

Comment: Luckily i have a spare display , but the problem is my laptop wont turn on with a that other screen is connected. Yeah I was hoping that i'll get away with spending just a little money for a laptop wich I found on a street in Norway :)  Not a new one ,it's an Acer aspire 1640z, and gosh the cooling design is the worst i ever seen in a laptop.  Thanks for answer tho :)

Comment: Wow, I never have that luck :/ ... and yeah, can't beat free!

Comment: Alright so i tested the other screen, it is white ,meaning the bulb is the problem . Thank you for educating me :) Never knew hardware can be so "mystical"